# Gravity in the Cyclone Physics Engine

Tags: c++

I'm building up a 2D physics engine in c++ based on the Cyclone Physics Engine, http://procyclone.com, and I'm trying to figure out why the code uses a gravity vector multiplied by the mass to add force to an object,

```
void psiclone::Gravity::addForce(Body* body, double seconds) {
    body->addForce(gravity * body->mass);
}
```

instead of

```
body->addForce(gravity * seconds);
```

Granted, the code does provide an update() including

```
velocity.mX += acceleration.getX() * seconds;
```

but with 2 objects being effected by gravity, shouldn't they both hit the ground at the same time even if they have different masses??

Comment: `body->addForce(gravity*seconds)` is physically incorrect, you are saying that you are adding a force, but you're giving it a velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the replies;  Upon further investigation I was missing a line in my update function ( cyclone's particle::integrate() ) multiplying the acceleration vector by the body's inverseMass:

```
acceleration *= inverseMass;
velocity += acceleration * seconds;
position += velocity * seconds;
```

This allowed two body's of differing mass to both fall to the bottom of the screen and hit at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

From physics, we know that `force = mass * acceleration`. Thus to calculate acceleration, they just divide `force` by `mass`. They are just sticking with physics definitions of the terms. `gravity * seconds` would be `velocity`.